# Using zypper, how can I remove all packages installed from a specific repository?

Tags: opensuse, rpm, zypper

Say I've added a repository using `zypper ar`. Then, I've gone and installed multiple packages from that repository, but now I want to remove all of them.

Is there a command that allows me to remove all the packages that I've installed just from that specific repository?

Answer (score 8):

I think there is no such command. You can list packages from specific repository:

```
zypper search --installed-only --repo devel:tools
```

or all orphaned packages if you've already removed that repository:

```
zypper packages --orphaned
```

Then you could try to `cut` package names from the output and pass it to `zypper remove` if it's worth the effort.

Comment: My openSuSE 12.3 system does not have the `--orphaned` option, but this might work: `zypper packages -i -R`: it lists the installed package in Reverse order of repository.

Comment: `--orphaned` was added in zypper 1.9.2 (https://github.com/openSUSE/zypper/issues/34)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `zypper search`, `awk` and `xargs` to remove all packages from a repository. For example:

```
zypper se --repo openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Debug --installed | awk '/^i(\+|\s)/ {print $3}' | xargs sudo zypper rm
```

Comment: `awk '/^i(\+|\s)/ {print $3}'` to match all installed packages (i or i+)

Comment: @Mesco zypper itself should only print installed packages when using `--installed`.

Comment: right, using `-i` or `--installed-only`. But also I've search for i and i+ at the beggining to skip first few rows (`Loading repository data...`). Maybe there are better methods, to skip first 5 rows but if you already use regex... ;)

Comment: maybe I'm using different zypper version (1.14.4) but its man says that the order should be `se [options] [query]` so your solution didn't work.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your concern. I updated the answer. About the search-syntax: I only use options and no query, so the order is correct I think.

Answer (score 0):

This line works fine for me

```
zypper search --installed-only --repo yourbadrepo|awk {'print $3'}|xargs sudo zypper rm
```

If you want to risk or use in a script, the -n option avoid confirm(can break deps)

```
  zypper search --installed-only --repo yourbadrepo|awk {'print $3'}|xargs sudo zypper -n rm
```